# select within if add block code

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a selection and I wanted to search a column of a table by left join only if the User is enabled with the pre condition to essar search as a condition that adds tables I was a little confused, I do not know if I separate searches or I do everything at once ....
He says it's for me to look at the mysql system, but I see so

```
if .condition... then ... end if;
```

My code

```
select user. * from
u user
if (u.visible == 1,
   left join houseUser hu on u.id = h.id_user
   left join h house on hu.id_house = h.id_house
)
where
u.age> 30
```

if visible add that code to can see in what house the user is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just incorporate the condition into the `on` clauses:

```
select u.*, hu.*, h.*
from user u left join
     houseUser hu
     on u.id = h.id_user and u.visible = 1 left join
     h house
     on hu.id_house = h.id_house and u.visible = 1
where u.age > 30;
```

The columns will come back, but they will be `NULL` when `visible` is not `1`.